# AO Smith Hot Water Heater Not Starting - Pressure Switch - Suggestions?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I’m having an issue with my hot water heater and kind of at a loss for what to try next…

A few days ago, we noticed the hot water stopped working. I thought one of the kids turned it off or something but that wasn’t the case. I found the Honeywell controller was on but blinking 3 times - “Pressure Switch Failed Open”. Power off/then on after 10 seconds or 10 minutes several times and all got the same result.

Our house is a new build and only 3 years old and hot water heater was installed when new. I checked for the exhaust pipe being blocked outside but it seemed fine. When it kicks on and attempts to start I can feel a pretty strong airflow at the end of the pipe outside.

After reading more, got into troubleshooting the pressure switch. By bypassing the switch this seemed to solve the problem, so I was under the impression this was the faulty part. I also checked with ohm meter and showed 1 no matter what, so I ordered a replacement pressure switch. When it got here, I had the same result though. For starters, turns out I was just testing it wrong (ohm meter will give a valid reading as long as I blow into it to close the switch) and I get the same results on both. So that doesn’t seem to be the issue…

Checked the hose and nipple between the switch and fan and that seems fine (also tried 2 diff hoses). After that, disconnected the exhaust pipe from the fan and tried it and it fires up and works fine. If I replace the pipe after about 30-60 seconds the pressure switch opens again and will shut down. That said, seems to indicate the flow between the fan and pressure switch is okay and unblocked.

So that would lead me to believe there is some blockage in the exhaust pipe, but I’m just not sure how that would happen. As mentioned, this is a newer house so it seems like the chance for blockage is small, outside exhaust has the rodent screen fully in tact, I can’t see any signs that debris or anything else was going in there, and I get a strong air flow outside when the fan does kick on. I also don’t really know how to even clean out the exhaust pipe without cutting PVC and taking it all apart since it’s sealed at every joint and would become a lot of work.

Any suggestions on next steps to figure this out? Could it be the fan is starting go and adding the pipe causes just enough back pressure to trip the pressure switch?

If it’s the some kind of blockage, any advice on finding and cleaning the blockage if there is one?

[image: Hot Water Heater Fan]

Small Update: Also just checked the airflow coming to the burner and that is also looking fine. I have one of these black vents that attach to the outside and everything was clean.

Comment: Have you contacted AO Smith to find out what the warranty period is on your water heater? Even after 3 years, I'm willing to bet it's still under warranty. They may even cover having a plumber come out to diagnose and do the repair, not just parts.

Comment: If your controller thinks the pressure switch is open have you traced the wiring ? Getting a 1 usually means 1 ohm and that is basically a short or closed, since your bypass worked could you have wiggled the wiring because the bypass checked the electronics on the board.